# Making sense of をと

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-を, particle-と

> どのような状況下であっても必ず十分な結果**をと**思い必死に過ごした３か月でした。

I'm only able to understand "No matter what circumstances you are put through..." and then something about producing sufficient results- the words that follow are what I can't make sense of in a sentence.

I don't understand how を and と (after 結果) can be used together since they're both conjunctive words.

Answer (score 3):

A verb and symbols are omitted in this sentence. Read it like this:

> **「**どのような状況下であっても、必ず十分な結果を**（出したい）」**と思い**、**
>
>   必死に過ごした３か月でした。

Comment: Maybe I'm saying something too obvious to everyone, but just for the record, the omission of verb here isn't an odd one but in fact an established usage in literary language. You can close a sentence with を when it intends "bring" or "make".

Comment: Or "want", "need", "give"... "休暇を!" "消費税の廃止を!"

Comment: If used towards other people, it's demanding for. If towards themselves, it's aspiring for. In either case it carries "desire for the unobtained" nuance.

Answer (score 2):

A classic example of unfinished sentences in Japanese.
You can make better sense with some brackets:

> **「** どのような状況下であっても必ず十分な結果を **」** と思い必死に過ごした３か月でした。

Can be translated something like:

> It was frantic 3 months I spent to get the result, thinking "No matter what the cirsumstances are, I will..."